# Upgrading error

Tags: debian, apt

When I do apt-get update // apt-get upgrade i received this error whatever I do:

```
root@debian:~# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 curl : Depends: libcurl3 (= 7.26.0-1+wheezy3) but 7.21.0-2.1+squeeze2 is installed
 multiarch-support : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.13-5) but 2.11.3-4 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
root@debian:~#
```

This is not my server so I don´t know what is installed inside, the only thing I know is that I need to upgrade the php from 5.2 minimum to 5.3. The told me that Zend Server is installed but I don´t know which version either. The first thing I tried is this and everytime I get this error. 
cat /etc/issue says:
Debian GNU/Linux 6.0 \n \l

This is my /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
root@debian:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.6 _Squeeze_ - Official i386 NETINST Binary-1 20120930-15:55]/ squeeze main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.6 _Squeeze_ - Official i386 NETINST Binary-1 20120930-15:55]/ squeeze main

deb http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main
deb-src http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main

deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main

# squeeze-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main
deb http://ftp2.de.debian.org/debian squeeze main non-free
deb http://repos.zend.com/zend-server/deb server non-free
root@debian:~#
```

and this is my output using apt-get install -f curl:

```
root@debian:~# apt-get install -f curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
curl is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 curl : Depends: libcurl3 (= 7.26.0-1+wheezy3) but 7.21.0-2.1+squeeze2 is to be installed
 multiarch-support : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.13-5) but 2.11.3-4 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Did you do what it told you to do?

Comment: You seem to be trying to mix wheezy and squeeze.  You can't just do that.  You need to fix your sources, your pinning.

Comment: @Michael Hampton I did try doing what it says of course.

Comment: @Zoredache yep, It seems to, but how can I fix this problem? thx

Comment: If you did, then where is the output?

Comment: @MichaelHampton here it is

Comment: It says: "Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages".

Comment: @Zoredache is most likely correct. Check your [pinning](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences#Pinning) and update your question accordingly. You're getting a Wheezy package reference from somewhere, and it doesn't look to be your sources list (unless there's more to it, e.g. in /etc/apt/sources.list.d).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling /etc/apt/sources.list.d is empty and there is not pinning configured

Comment: @MichaelHampton it works! thanks! I was freeking out! can you answer the question to give you the correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original error also gives the solution:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
```

If you haven't seen this before, you have to run *exactly* that command. Doing otherwise, you get:

```
Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

This usually fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Michael has already provided the [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88015/3879) to fix the dependency issues. Just to note further, `apt-get upgrade` would upgrade all the installed packages. If you want to [upgrade only a single package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44122/upgrade-a-single-package-with-apt-get), use `apt-get install package_name`. For PHP, it would likely be `apt-get install php5`.

Also, if there is frequent trouble with updating the package sources, you may revert back to the "official package lists" for the distribution. [Debian Source List Generator](http://debgen.simplylinux.ch/) provides an interactive interface to generate the source lists for any distribution.